# Which solutions for background job processing exist for Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp

I need a solution for background job processing. A task queue, where workers can be remote processes on different machines.

I've searched over internet, but found only [Psychiq](https://github.com/fukamachi/psychiq) which is in alfa and not recommended for production.

I don't belive that for the such mature language as Common Lisp there isn't other solutions.

Where they are?

**Update**:

Possible solutions:

- [lfarm](https://lparallel.org/2013/06/15/introducing-lfarm/) (suggested by @coredump).
- Gearman with client/worker using [cl-gearman](https://github.com/taksatou/cl-gearman) (found by myself in yet another google session).

Comment: You want some interface to POSIX system calls. They are not standardized in Common Lisp, but most CL implementations (e.g. [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)....) have a good one. See [SBCL extensions](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Extensions) chapter and its `sb-ext` & `sb-posix` modules.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no, I want to be able to put task into the queue and be able to process this task on another machine.

Comment: I was going to suggest [cl-async](http://orthecreedence.github.io/cl-async/), but I think your comment on executing on a remote machine rules that out. You should probably add it to your question.

Comment: @BartvanNierop updated a question.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but [LFARM](https://lparallel.org/2013/06/15/introducing-lfarm/) might be a good candidate:

> lfarm is a distributed version of lparallel which replaces worker threads with remote processes. For example lfarm:pmap will subdivide the input sequence(s), send the parts to remote machines for mapping, and then combine the results. Likewise lfarm:future wraps remote task execution in the metaphor of promises. Most of the lparallel kernel API is retained with minor variations.

The [github repository](https://github.com/lmj/lfarm) has some examples.

See also [Erlangen](http://mr.gy/blog/erlangen-intro.html) for a distributed Erlang-like approach based on native threads.

> Erlangen brings distributed, asynchronous message passing to Clozure Common Lisp. It orchestrates Clozure CL processes (native threads) using message passing, and encourages fault tolerant software architectures using supervison trees. It is also transparently distributed, all its features work seamlessly across IP networks. Thus, it can be used to build applications across multiple Clozure CL instances on different hosts. Erlangen borrows many ideas from Erlang/OTP, hence the name. (Its a town!)

Comment: Wow, that looks interesting, I have to investigate it further.